# Does Memory allocation in C is a machine dependent?

Tags: c, unix, memory, malloc

Does Memory allocation in C is a machine dependent?
I want my  program to be transferred from a UNIX system to another system without any problem.

Comment: Well, `malloc` and friends internally use lower-level system calls (which in the case of Linux would be `sbrk`/`brk` and `mmap`), but so long as you keep using `malloc` and friends only and not those system calls, I don't think there should be a major change that could break the whole program.

Comment: My gut feeling tells me that you should read up on serialisation/deserialisation. Just read some basic description of those terms, if you do not see any relation to what you are trying to do you are fine and my gut feeling was wrong. ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mediocrevegetable1 said in the comments, as long as you use functions from the standard library, it should work. (But just make sure that you used an ANSI C compiler before, and to use an ANSI C compiler when compiling for another system. You can see [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#Compilers_supporting_ANSI_C) a list of ANSI C compilers.)